# cookie-universal-nuxt, Page refresh loss cookie data on server

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

i'm using vuejs, nuxtjs implement cookie-universal-nuxt package.Localhost work everything,but the server does not work after refreshing page.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
    export default {
     mode: 'universal',
     ssr: true,
     target: 'server',
     modules: ['cookie-universal-nuxt'],
     server: {
       port: 4002,
       host: 'localhost'
     }
   }
```

**cart.js**

```
$cookies.set('cart', cookieParams, {
   path: '/',
   maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using babel, try adding the package to the [transpile](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/#transpile) section in your nuxt.config. Some packages don't work in ssr correctly without this, e.g element-ui, @vuebits/bem, etc.